# Rails 3 Filter Array values in View with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

rails 3.1 runy 1.92 Trying to allow users to filter on a list of products using the product type attribute and have the list updated asynchronously via AJAX after they make a selection.

My approach was to create instance variables for each product type  and an instance variable to hold the users selection result like so

```
  @auto = Product.where(:type =>"auto") #assign all products w/ type=auto to @auto
  @filter_selection = @products # this value defaults to all products but would be updated to @auto or @home depending on users selection
```

My Javascript is extremely weak and my Ruby is only a little better any help is much appreciated.

Products Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible  :location, :price, :type,
TYPES = ["auto", "home", "garden"]
```

Store_Controller (Note This is the store controller and not the Product controller)

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
def index

#instance variables to filter on product type
@auto = Product.where(:type =>"auto")
@home = Product.where(:type =>"home")
@garden = Product.where(:type =>"garden")

@products = products.all
@filter_selection = @products #all products listed by default

#filter Products array based on users selection
@products = @auto if @filter_selection == "auto"
@products = @home if @filter_selection == "home"
@products = @garden if @filter_selection == "garden"

respond_to do |format|
...
end 
end
```

Store_Controller's Index View

```
<div class="products_list">
<%=select_tag "dept-filter", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, "id", "dept"), :prompt => "All Departments", :remote => true%>

 <%@products.each do |product|%>
 <%=product.price%>
 ...
 </div>
 <%end%>

 <script>
$(document).ready ->
    $("#dept-filter").on "change", ->
     $.ajax
     type: "GET"
     dataType: "script"
     data:
       dept_type: $("#dept-filter").val()
  </script>
```

Index.js.erb

```
 $('.products_list').html("<%= j render("products_list") %>").fadeIn('slow');
```

So my questions are basically
1- how do i bind the result of the users selection to my @filter_selection variable 
2- How do I get it to update via AJAX

Answer (score 0):

In product model use this code:

```
  def self.filer_by(type)
   Product.where(type: type)
  end
```

In store controller use:

```
@products = Product.filer_by(@filter_selection)
```

Try do that in Ajax request:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready ->
   $("#dept-filter").on "change", ->
   $.ajax
    type: "GET"
    dataType: "script"
    url: 'stores/index', 
    data:
      dept_type: $("#dept-filter").val()
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks @mohamed yakot This seems to have put me on the right path but now all products are missing when i load the page and the drop down only shows the prompt. Should i have made a change to the view as well? I think what I may need to bind the users selection to "@filter_selection". Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: still no luck with the update same thing happenning as before. any other suggestions? is the code in my index.js.erb file correct?